# Sending mass email w/ CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

So, what I want to accomplish is this. I want to have a nice UI where an administrator can go and type an email, then hits send.

When send is hit, it goes through the database, finds all users that are subscribed to emails and grabs their email address. It then sends the email to those users in a loop.

I've got that created and it's working fine. However, this isn't sustainable as far as I'm led to believe with what I've been reading if I have a few thousand users for example, or more.

What I've been reading is I should be setting up a task in the background to actually send the emails. From what I've read and understood I should be doing this with a Shell, http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell. So my only idea to solve this is to save the email to the database, create a shell that goes through a set amount of users and emails that email in the database to them (how many is good practice?), and then attach that shell to a cron job that will run at a certain iteration (what would be a good iteration?) until all users have been processed.

What I don't like about this solution is that then this cron job will either run all the time, even when there are no emails to be sent, so I'll have to either mark an email as sent once it has processed all users or delete the email. But either way, this cron job will always run this script which will always have to make at least one database call, unless I turn it off. Which then means there may be a manual step to enable the cron when I want to send an email and disable it when I don't want to.

So what I'm wondering is, is this the accepted way to solve this problem, or is there a better way that resolves my issues with my current solution?

Comment: Your question is very broad, and its current form basically asking for a step-by-step guide garnished with opinions, which is kinda offtopic for StackOverflow. Please narrow down your question to some more specific, isolated, programming related problems.

Comment: @ndm Sorry, thanks for the comment. I've expanded what I know about the potential solution and narrowed down my question to something more specific. Is that better?